# Which of the following is true statement?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V(F)\rightarrow V(F)$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2=0$,then which of the following is true-

$(a)\,\dim(R(T))\leq \dim(N(T)) $

$(b)\,\dim(N(T))\leq \dim(R(T)) $

$(c)\,\dim(N(T))= \dim(R(T)) $

Solution: $T^2=0\implies T(T(x))=0 \forall x\in V(F)$
$$T(x)=0\implies x=0$$
Hence, $\dim(N(T))=0$. Thus, $\dim(N(T))\leq \dim(R(T)) $.

But,the answer givn in answer key is $(a)$.

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: What? If $\dim(N(T))=0$ then it's impossible to have $T^2=0$ unless $V(F)=0.$ Note that $T\circ T=0\implies R(T)\subset N(T).$

Comment: Your error is in assuming that $T(x)=0$ only if $x=0$. This would be true if $T$ were invertible, but it clearly isn't invertible.

Comment: Also, do you multiply a matrix by a vector with the matrix being on the right side of the vector?

Answer (score 3):

$T^2=O \implies R (T)\subset N (T)\implies dimR (T)\leq dimN (T) $

Answer (score 2):

I do not have enough votes to comment so i'm asking my doubt here. I wanted to ask Matt Samuel,how to decide "Whether the given linear transformation is invertible,if nothing is mentioned about the dimension of the vector space on which the linear transformation is defined"?

Comment: If $Tx=0\implies x=0$ then $T$ is a bijection from $V(F)$ to $R(T).$  If $V(F)$ is infinite-dimensional this does not imply that $R(T)=V(F),$  However it does imply that the linear bijection $U:R(T)\to V(F)$ exists, where $UTx=x$ for all $x\in V(F),$ and we cannot have that in conjunction with $T^2=0$ unless $V(F)=\{0\}$ (the zero-dimensional vector-space).

Comment: More simply, if $T^2=0$ and $\forall x\in V(F)\; (Tx=0\implies x=0)$ then, for clarity let $y_x=Tx$ and we have $\forall x \in V(F)\;(\; T^2x=0\implies$ $ Ty_x=0\implies y_x=0\implies Tx=0\implies x=0\;).$